# Отправка фото Telegram Bot через Python requests

Tags: python, telegram-bot, requests

Как отправить фотографию пользователю, используя requests?
Пробую этот код

```
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<_token_>/sendPhoto'

with open('foto.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post(url=url, data={'chat_id': '111111111', 'photo': f})
    print(r.json())
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: wrong URL host'}
```

При использовании других методов в переменной `url`, выводятся ошибки:

```
{'ok': False, 'error_code': 404, 'description': 'Not Found: method not found'}
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Ссылка на [**документацию метода sendPhoto**](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto)

При вставке в переменную `f` ссылки на изображение из интернета, отсылает корректно. Но как отправлять свой собственный файл?

Comment: А почему вручную делаете а не через одну из библиотек для работы с ботом телеграмма? Пример отправки картинки: https://github.com/gil9red/telegram__url2image_bot/blob/master/main.py#L84

Comment: Требуемые задачи от бота крайне элементарны(периодическая отсылка фотографии). Более того есть опыт работы с API Vkontakte и Одноклассники, в которых подобные конструкции кода работали без нареканий, а вот API Telegram вызвал сложности

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<Token>/sendPhoto";
files = {'photo': open('foto.jpg', 'rb')}
data = {'chat_id' : "111111111"}
r= requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
print(r.json())
```

так-же необходимо обязательно убедиться, что chat_id существует, в противном случае телеграмм вернет ошибку